# Google Chrome - Profile could not be opened correctly error

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome

I am wondering if someone might be able to help me out.

I suddenly (well I believe it happened after some ubuntu system updates recently) have issues when going into Chrome with it complaining that the profile could not be opened correctly. I have tried many of the suggested fixes (which all work for a total of one launch of the program). What I'm finding is if I kill all google/chrome processes it won't give the profile error on next launch, it seems that chrome is not cleaning exiting (I have turned on the setting to not run chrome in the background... this made no difference). I've done an apt-get purge to clean before re-installing... did nothing to alleviate this issue. Chromium doesn't have the same issue.

Ideas? *(On Version 45.0.2454.85 (64-bit) Google Chrome)*
Ubuntu 12.04

PS: Also around this same time Firefox lost it's Minimize/Close buttons on the top right. I can only close it with alt-f4 now.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Your profile could not be opened correctly." while opening Chrome/ium](http://askubuntu.com/questions/368279/your-profile-could-not-be-opened-correctly-while-opening-chrome-ium)

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=527318 and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2293308

Comment: Ahhh multiple people same problem in one of those articles, apparently fixed in beta... i'm trying that now...Thanks guy!

Comment: Just to confirm some other peoples posts, by installing the beta from http://pkgs.org/download/google-chrome-beta  I was able to make chrome not throw the profile error everytime. This is a suitable workaround until hopefully the next stable firefox release.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.

anyways. do:

```
cd ~/.config/google-chrome
```

then run

```
sudo rm -rf *
```

WARNING: THIS WILL MAKE CHROME RESET EVERYTHING! YOU WILL LOSE ALL BOOKMARKS!

This should fix this.

Answer (score -1):

Try running

```
killall -9 chrome
```

Before starting chrome.