# Why does killall (sometimes?) needs to be applied twice?

Tags: command-line, process, kill, killall

Why does killall (sometimes?) need to be applied twice? Here's an [example](https://askubuntu.com/a/572252/16023) where a "double" `killall` is needed to end the process.

When and why does a process needed to be killed "twice"? What happens under the bonnet?

Comment: [...voodoo programming](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/V/voodoo-programming.html)

Comment: Or run `killall -9` ... *once*.

Comment: That example should not need 2 killalls. Chrome probably will start a clean up process (clearing cache etc.) that will take a bit of time. The 2nd one probably "works" because the 1st one actually ended.

Comment: @Rinzwind does the 2nd one possibly "override" the *grace period* (which I found [loosely being referred to in a number of other posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856624/using-appropriate-posix-signals))? Is there a way/flag to verbosely monitor the *grace period* "count-down"? Is there some hard evidence / source code to confirm the "override" hypothesis?

Comment: The override is the "-9"  as muru stated.

Comment: @Rinzwind the "-9" override is *not* the same as the double "-15" override (even if the eventual outcome is equivalent) -- plz prove me wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to state a application-specific possibility.

When you use `killall program`, a `SIGTERM` (signal 15) is sent to the program. The usual response to `SIGTERM` is that the program would exit gracefully.

Now as the `SIGTERM` is catchable, a program can have a signal handler for `SIGTERM` that would do some task upon receiving the first `SIGTERM` (first `killall`) and return to a state where the second `SIGTERM` would just terminate it (default action). This is highly dependent on the developer of the program of course and not a general case.